# Converting a string of numbers into predetermined variables in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, converters

I want to convert a long string of numbers(PI) into individually set variables by assigning each digit(0-9) with a letter. Example:(when the compiler sees a digit and it is "1", "1" will always be 
assigned var a, the same with "2" as it will always be assigned to var b....etc.

```
var rawPi = 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9;
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3; 
var d = 4; 
var e = 5;
var f = 6;
var g = 7; 
var h = 8;
var i = 9;
var j = 0;
//Tried to make an array out of the digits of PI
var cookedPi = rawPi.split(' ').map(Number);

var i;
while(i < pi.length )
  {
    cookedPi.toString()[for(i = 0; i < pi.length; i++){
      if(i= a) 
      console.log("a");
//This segement didn't print out "a", so I didn't bother to write an IF statement for the rest of the values.
                      }];

  }
```

I tried to use loops in order for the compiler to read each digit individually but that's where I think I went wrong. Also part of the problem is I don't know how to isolate the errors because I don't know where I went wrong. Can somebody explain this, I am somewhat of a novice.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, you probably want an array, or an object, not hundreds of variables. To find errors in the code try http://jshint.com; you have a few...

Comment: What `varPi` is supposed to be? A string?

Comment: Perhaps `var rawPi = '3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9';`.

Comment: You don't even know how to write basic Javascript. I suggest learning the syntax before tackling this problem.

Comment: you do not have pi variable any where in the code.

Comment: JavaScript is not a compiled language. You reference to `compiler` is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be struggling with basic javascript, consider the following:

```
// split is a string method, so maybe you want rawPi to be a string
// so it can be split later
var rawPi = '3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9';
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3; 
var d = 4; 
var e = 5;
var f = 6;
var g = 7; 
var h = 8;
var i = 9;
var j = 0;

//Tried to make an array out of the digits of PI
var cookedPi = rawPi.split(' ').map(Number);
```

The following is messed up:

```
var i;
while(i < pi.length )
  {
    cookedPi.toString()[for(i = 0; i < pi.length; i++){
```

You probably want:

```
for (var i=0; i<cookedPi.length; i++) {
```

The following is an assignment, not a comparison:

```
      if(i= a)
```

You want:

```
      if (i == a) {
        console.log("a");
      }
```

and so on.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it probably helps the OP more than an actual answer so have my +1 anyway.